# Populating Jtable from multiple sqlite tables

Tags: java, sqlite

I have three database tables with their respective columns as follows:

studentinfo: (studentid, name)
Balance: (studentid, balance)
Amount: (studentid, amount)

I would like to display studentid, name, balance, amount on a JTable directly from the database. I retrieved these information from the tables and store in a Map before displaying on my JTable. But the values keep repeating on my JTable as you can see in the output picture attached. 
Here is my code:

```
string ="select studentinfo.studentid,name,balance,amount from studentinfo     inner join Balance on studentinfo.studentid = Balance.studentid inner join Amount on studentinfo.studentid = Amount.studentid"        
  while(rs.next()){                
       for(i = 0, k=1,p=2,m=3; i < 1 && k < 2 && p<3 && m<4; i++,k++,p++,m++)  //JTable colums
        {
           for(j = 0; j < rs.getRow(); j++)  // Jtable rows
           {           
           id = rs.getString("studentid");
           name = rs.getString("name");   
           amt = rs.getDouble("amount");
           bal = rs.getDouble("balance"); 

           map1.put(id, name);
           map2.put(id, amt);
           map3.put(id, bal);                     
          }
          j--   // change the value of j=0 to always start from the first row of a new column in the JTable;


                Set set = map1.entrySet();
                Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry ent = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
                table.setValueAt(ent.getKey(), j, k);
                table.setValueAt(ent.getValue(), j, i);
                }

                Set set1 = map2.entrySet();
                Iterator iterator1 = set1.iterator();
                while(iterator1.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry ent1 = (Map.Entry)iterator1.next();
                table.setValueAt(ent1.getValue(), j, p);
                }

                Set set2 = map2.entrySet();
                Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
                while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry ent2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
                table.setValueAt(ent2.getValue(), j, m);
                }
       }
```

}

Output:

[Output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj5aU.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are iterating over the same row again and again and I think you are complicating things, the code can be a lot simpler if you set the value to the `table` as follows:

```
int rowCount=0;
while(rs.next()){   
    table.setValueAt(rs.getString("studentid"),rowCount, 0);
    table.setValueAt(rs.getString("name"), rowCount, 1);
    table.setValueAt(rs.getDouble("amount"), rowCount, 2);
    table.setValueAt(rs.getDouble("balance"), rowCount, 3);

    rowCount++;//increment the row count for each row fetched
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, It works fine. But because setValueAt() uses Object,int,int as parameters. I therefore rewrite the code as follows:

Comment: Thanks alot @javaguy

Comment: The whole code will be 5-6 lines now, which clean and easy to understand